# Pass a param to component Providers In Angular

Tags: angular, inheritance, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Component that inherits from another -

```
@Component({
  template: '',
  providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => TComp),        
        multi: true,
      },
  ]
})
export abstract class FormBase<TComp> implements ControlValueAccessor {
   ...
   ...
}
```

And Another component -

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-button',
   templateUrl: './button.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
})
export class ButtomComponent extends FormBase<ButtomComponent> {
   ...
   ...
}
```

I want to be able to pass a reference of child component to parent component, so parent can add the provider instead of child (which may look as shown above),
I want to extend this behavior and inherit the FormBase in other components and avoid declaring the NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR provider in every child component,

I couldn't find a proper way to do it, I get an error cannot find name - TComp,
Will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you inherit a class, it does not inherit the `@Component` decorator contents, so any way you look at it, you never import the parent contents outside the class, so you have to declare them individually.

You can just write a utility function that will reduce your code size, like shown below

utility

```
export const addProviders = (component: any) => {
  return {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => component),
    multi: true,
  };
};
```

child component

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { addProviders, ParentComponent } from '../parent/parent.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  providers: [addProviders(ChildComponent)],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ParentComponent],
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d2evbs)

Comment: Thanks @Naren I guess this is the correct and probably only approach